# Cannot Load Page Items

Tags: magento-2.1, template, exception

On the front page of our site, some of the modules are not loading with a simple error message in place. "We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email"

On looking in the exception log a Critical error exception is being thrown. can anyone offer some advice as to how to resolve this issue or where I should start with trying to trace the fault. I am presently using Magento 2.1.3.

> [2017-01-12 10:51:26] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Warning:
>   getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   /home/vaperit5/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php
>   on line 304 in
>   /home/vaperit5/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
>   Stack trace: 0 [internal function]:
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'getimagesize():...',
>   '/home/vaperit5/...', 304, Array) 1
>   /home/vaperit5/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php(304): getimagesize('') 2
>   /home/vaperit5/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php(289): Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AbstractAdapter->getImageType() 3
>   /home/vaperit5/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php(59):
>   Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AbstractAdapter->getMimeType()

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally solved this issue. There seems to be a permissions problem with the vendor library and deleting the vendor folder and the composer lock file and reinstalling the vendor libraries solved the problem.

This version of Magento was the composer install so problem solved in case anyone else has the same issue... A very misleading message in the exception log..